# Can an AngularJS Directive Require One Directive or Another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can an AngularJS directive be set to require one directive or another?

I am creating two types of buttons which open a menu with additional options.

```
<dropdown-button>
</dropdown-button>
```

Which will behave similar to Bootstrap's drop down button.

[image]

and another...

```
<split-dropdown-button>
</split-dropdown-button>
```

That behaves as the split button alternative.

[image]

Both require a menu definition, which is done in exactly the same way, so I'd like to create a (for example) `button-menu` directive that requires `dropdown-button` **or** `split-dropdown-button`.

Is this possible?

What alternatives are there if a directive can only *fully* require one or more?

Comment: Why not array the require with optional on both types of directives and if both are absent throw an exception in the link function?

Comment: Can you elaborate and put in an answer? I'm familiar with arrays in require, but not the ability to make them optional, and throwing an exception if they are not found.

Comment: Why is the value of your `require` wrapped in a string? It should just be a regular array.

Comment: @user2943490 - ARGH! The tree got lost in the forest. I left the quotes when I changed my require to an array and totally missed it. Just couldn't see them as I looked over everything - again - and again - and again. Thanks for spotting that... it fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon, working off a tablet, but here is some pseudo code:

```
app.directive('buttonMenu', function(){ 
return {
require: ['?dropdownButton', '?dropdownSplitButton'],
restrict: 'E',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
if(!controllers[0] && !controllers[1])
//freak out
else
//scope things
```